# Angular nested children routing error: "Cannot match any routes. URL Segment'"

Tags: typescript, angular-routing, angular12

So far in this project I have a main component with lazy-loading, and I want to load a modal using routes, so I can access specific content with just the url. But I'm getting an error when trying to access the child route. My code:

My App routing module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'users',
    loadChildren: () => import('./users-list/users-list.module').then(m => m.UsersListModule)
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'users',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

UsersListComponent loads just fine. Here is the UsersListRoutingModule:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { UserModalComponent } from '../shared/components/user-modal/user-modal.component';
import { UsersListComponent } from './users-list.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: UsersListComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: "child",
        component: UserModalComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class UsersListRoutingModule { }
```

UsersListModule:

```
import { UsersListRoutingModule } from './users-list-routing.module';
import { UserModalComponent } from '../shared/components/user-modal/user-modal.component';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    UsersListRoutingModule
  ]
})
export class UsersListModule { }
```

I have a router-outlet in the UsersListComponent:

```
<div class="table">
    <app-table
        [data]="usersDataSource"
        [displayedColumns]="tableColumns"
        (onViewAction)="showUserInfo($event)"
    >
    </app-table>
</div>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

On the event click of a button in the app-table component, it triggers the "showUserInfo()", which it's being called. It executes the following code:

```
showUserInfo(user: UserData) {
    this.selectedUserData = user;
    this.router.navigate(['/child']);
}
```

But when it redirects to the child root, I get this error:

> vendor.js:29385 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot
> match any routes. URL Segment: 'child' Error: Cannot match any routes.
> URL Segment: 'child'

I already tried using:

```
this.router.navigate(['child']);
```

and:

```
this.router.navigate(['child'], { relativeTo: this.route }]);
```

and even:

```
this.router.navigate(['/child'], { relativeTo: this.route }]);
```

What am I missing here?